# Logcat tells me it could not find a method

Tags: android, onclick

When I press a button the activity should switch. I originally used onClick in the XML to start the method but after reading many answers about it I changed to a listener. However it is still not working.
Also when I click on blank space in the first activity the app crashes with the same error.

Please help!

MenuActivity:

```
package com.milkywhy.unidigid;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_layout);   

    Button btnNextScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verify);

  //Listening to button event
          btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VerifyActivity.class);
                startActivity(nextScreen);
            }
          });

        Button btnNextScreen2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.how);

  //Listening to button event
          btnNextScreen2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent nextScreen2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HowItWorksActivity.class);
                startActivity(nextScreen2);
            }
          });

        Button btnNextScreen3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getIt);

  //Listening to button event
          btnNextScreen3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent nextScreen3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IDActivity.class);
                startActivity(nextScreen3);
            }
          });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Here is the logCat:

```
09-14 17:25:16.034: D/dalvikvm(16194): Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-14 17:25:18.006: D/libEGL(16194): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
09-14 17:25:18.066: D/libEGL(16194): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
09-14 17:25:18.076: D/libEGL(16194): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
09-14 17:25:18.117: D/OpenGLRenderer(16194): Enabling debug mode 0
09-14 17:25:18.227: D/dalvikvm(16194): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 9% free 9619K/10567K, paused 16ms+4ms, total 99ms
09-14 17:55:23.522: D/AndroidRuntime(16194): Shutting down VM
09-14 17:55:23.522: W/dalvikvm(16194): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fe62a0)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method verify(View) in the activity class com.milkywhy.unidigid.MenuActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RelativeLayout
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3647)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: verify [class android.view.View]
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3640)
09-14 17:55:23.542: E/AndroidRuntime(16194):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: can you please post the logcat..

Comment: I've now posted the logcat

Comment: Problem solved. After a long time searching I found that I had put an onClick in the layout.xml in regards to the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the method not found error during your call to `getApplicationContext()`?

If so, can you try if `MenuActivity.this.getApplicationContext()` works instead ?

I've always been into VERY safe programming and so have made very less use of inner classes (let alone anonymous classes). Therefore, usually I use the same outer class (MenuActivity in this case) to handle the clicks. Hence, I'd be saying `this.getApplicationContext()`.

Now that we are inside an inner class, things might become a bit hazy.